# XSLT Global count of grouped items

Tags: xslt, sorting, count

I have a set of items which I am grouping using the muenchian method using keys.  This is working great, however when I try to do things with the first x number of items it is doing it on the x number of items in each group rather than across the whole set of results.  How would I get the individual position of each item accross the whole collection?

```
    <xsl:key name="pictures-by-productid" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" use="@ProductId" />


<xsl:template match="/">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; float:left;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="sub">

        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

and the second template

```
    <xsl:template match="/" mode="sub">    <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[count(. | key('pictures-by-productid', @ProductId)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('pictures-by-productid', @ProductId)">            
            <xsl:sort select="@PictureType" />                  
            <div style="float:left; margin:2px;">
            <img src="{@ThumbNailUrl}" width="58" /> <br />             
            Download            
            <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </div>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you provide the source xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:key 
  name="pictures-by-productid" 
  match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" 
  use="@ProductId"
/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <div style="border:1px solid red; float:left;">
    <!-- iterate the group, sorted by PictureType… -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[
      count(. | key('pictures-by-productid', @ProductId)[1]) = 1
    ]">
      <xsl:sort select="@PictureType">
      <!-- …and output only if among the fist 6 items -->
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 6">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
          mode="picture"
          select="key('pictures-by-productid', @ProductId)" 
        />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" mode="picture">
  <div style="float:left; margin:2px;">
    <img src="{@ThumbNailUrl}" width="58" /> <br />                         
    <xsl:text>Download </xsl:text>
    <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```